# How to call QDialog::exec in a separate tread avoiding any signals (including repaint) to main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, hook, assert

I want to create my oun ASSERT/VERIFY message box. So I use:

```
int _CrtSetReportHook(int reportType, char * message, int * returnValue)
```

The hook itself is:

```
int MyReportHook(int reportType, char * message, int * returnValue)
{
    ...
    QDialog assertDlg;
    ...
    assertDlg.exec();
}
```

It works, but if I have an ASSERT on paint event (in other tread, generally), I will crash. So... How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT**
Generally, I want to call QDialog::exec() while executing paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event). So, I need to prevent calling the whole QApplication's repainting (and processing any other signals for sure).

Comment: Why not avoid using assert if you don't want the application to crash?

Comment: @Huytard I believe he's referring to the fact that Qt will assert if you try to paint outside of the main thread.

Comment: @VALOD9 - You absolutely cannot execute Qt GUI code outside of the main GUI thread. Trying to exec a dialog would be utterly pointless if it can't paint itself.

Comment: @Chris, I understand that. So if ASSERT appeared not in a main thread, I move my QDialog to it. 
`QAssertDlgWrapper assertDialogWrapper;
assertDialogWrapper.moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
assertDialogWrapper.exec();`
So I want calling QDialog::exec() not to emit repainting of the whole QApplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: you can't. There are two solutions that will work from an arbitrary thread:

1. Use the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi.
2. Send a signal to a QObject that lives in the GUI thread. This signal will be received in the GUI thread and can interact with the user. If you care about the return value, you can use a synchronization object to wait for the GUI thread to indicate that the message box was processed and that the return value is available.